# Command Cooldown 1 minute not working discord bot

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Here I tried making a command cooldown so people wont be spamming and getting rich fast on my discord bot! The thing is though the code I wrote does not do what I want it to do! It just ignores `talkRecently` Here is my code:

```
var eco = require('discord-economy');
const editJsonFile = require("edit-json-file");

const prefix = '.'; 
const talkedRecently = new Set();

exports.run = async (client, message, args, ops) => {
    if (talkedRecently.has(message.author.id)) {
            message.channel.send("Wait 1 minute before getting typing this again. - " + message.author);
    } else {
            var job2 = ['actor/actress','astronaut','baker','barber','biologist','chef','doctor','dentist','farmer','nurse','jounalist','police officer','vet','vocalist','zoologist','waiter/waitress'];

            const user = message.author.id;
            var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (500 + 1));
            
            let check = eco.FetchBalance(user);
            if(!check) {
                eco.SetBalance(user, 0);
            }

            eco.AddToBalance(user, number)
                
            var job = job2[Math.floor(Math.random() * job2.length)];
            
            message.channel.send(`You have worked as a **${job}** and you have earned ${number}`);
        }

        talkedRecently.add(message.author.id);
        setTimeout(() => {
          // Removes the user from the set after a minute
          talkedRecently.delete(message.author.id);
        }, 60000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excluding boilerplate code

```
var arrayOfIntervalUsed = []
var arrOfIds = [];
client.on("message", (msg) => {

arrOfIds.push(msg.author.id)
if(arrOfIntervalUsed.indexOf(msg.author.id) === -1){
setInterval(() => { 
arrOfIntervalUsed.push(msg.author.id) // so the bot isn't duplicating itself
if(arrOfIds.filter(() => {
return msg.author.id 
}).length > 10){
msg.reply("Stop spamming")
arrOfIds = arrOfIds.filter(() => {
return !msg.author.id

})
}

}, 60000)
}
})
```

EDIT:
If you want none of the commands to work if they spam add a variable by default true which has to be true in your if statement for what command it is and in the code above below the message about stop spamming make it false but if you want it to come back on add another setInterval outside of that that a set amount of miliseconds it is restored.